# adjusts the size of gallery to fit into the screen without margin

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, gallery, margin

I tried to calculate the size of the image in my gallery such that all the images will fit into the screen without margin.
However, when the window is resized, the images are not fitted so well and there is a white margin.

## way that I am already tried:

1. I tried to change the style in css file, I add "margin: 0, padding :0" but seen to do nothing.
2. I tried to push the images to the left side, I change the style in css file to :  flex-wrap: wrap;
   display: inline-flex;
   but I didnt succeed to add more imges in the blank.
3. I tried to play with the calculation in function " calcImageSize() " but the magin stayed.

if someone see what is the problem I would like to get some help.
Tnx.

```
class Gallery extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    tag: PropTypes.string
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      images: [],
      galleryWidth: this.getGalleryWidth()
    };
  }

  getGalleryWidth(){
    try {
      return document.body.clientWidth;
    } catch (e) {
      return 1000;
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getImages(this.props.tag);
    this.setState({
      galleryWidth: document.body.clientWidth
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="gallery-root">
        {this.state.images.map(dto => {
          return <Image key={'image-' + dto.id} dto={dto} galleryWidth={this.state.galleryWidth}/>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```
class Image extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    dto: PropTypes.object,
    galleryWidth: PropTypes.number
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.calcImageSize = this.calcImageSize.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      size: 200
    };
  }

  calcImageSize() {
    const {galleryWidth} = this.props;
    const targetSize = 200;
    const imagesPerRow = Math.round(galleryWidth / targetSize);
    const size = (galleryWidth / imagesPerRow);
    this.setState({
      size
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.calcImageSize();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className="image-root"
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `url(${this.urlFromDto(this.props.dto)})`,
          width: this.state.size + 'px',
          height: this.state.size + 'px'
        }}
        >
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

#### GALLERY CSS

```
.gallery-root {
  text-align: center;
}

.gallery-header {
  background-color: #222;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20pt;
}

.gallery-intro {
  font-size: 15pt;
}
```

#### IMAGE CSS

```
.image-root {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid white;

  > div {
    visibility: hidden;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    white-space: pre;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

Comment: did you reset margin to body also ? did you use flex:1 or flex-grow:1 with max-width or any other attempt to fill entire rows ? ... Can you set up a snippet with the code that shows your issue ? (use fake image)

Comment: Hi, this is a link of snippet of the gallery with the white margin. I tried to put the photos from the left top corner and so on but unfortunately without succeed . 
[link](https://ibb.co/YfTtrvJ)
Thanks